# Python 3: hook list & dict changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, hook

My app relies on `list` and `dict` data structures for maintaining current state. Now I need to track whenever element is added/removed from list or dict data changes. I've googled and found out that there are `collections.abc.Sequence` (for list) and `collections.abc.MutableMapping` (for dict), but they're very limited and result can't be used instead of list/dict (`append`, `clear`, ...). I've been thinking about some proxy class that'll forward calls and provide hooks to be called before/after some method is forwarded, but didn't find anything that even looks like in.

So my question is: how do I hook mutators of given structures? Is there something I don't know?

Comment: The only way I come up with is implementing a subclass of list/dict on my own, then override the `append`, `clear`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclassing dict maybe:

```
class DictWatch(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.callback = kwargs.pop('callback')
        dict.__init__(self, args)

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        # YOUR HOOK HERE
        self.callback(key, val)
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)

    # and other overrided dict methods if you need them
```

Demo:

```
>>> def cb(k,v):
...     print k,v
... 
>>> d=DictWatch(callback=cb)
>>> d['key']='100'
key 100
```

Comment: I've seen some discussion stating that inheriting built-in types is a bad idea. Or is it wrong?

Comment: @Daniel: There is absolutely positively nothing wrong with inheriting from built-in types! That is silly.

Answer (score 5):

Even though subclassing built-in classes is officially supported, I'd still recommend you consider using a proxy class.

The problem is it isn't well documented when overriden methods are called. For instance, if you override `__setitem__` method, it won't be called when you modify your dict using `extend` method, e.g. `mydict.extend({"a": 42})`. You'll have to override `extend`, too. It's very easy to forget to override some obscure method, and modification will occur silently without your callback getting called (whereas if you were using a proxy, it would throw an `AttributeError` indicating that you forgot to define some method).

There's even more to that. Some built-in methods that receive a dictionary through argument will not call any overriden methods at all in CPython, as shown in the following [example from PyPy wiki](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#subclasses-of-built-in-types):

```
>>>> class D(dict):
....     def __getitem__(self, key):
....         return 42
....
>>>>
>>>> d1 = {}
>>>> d2 = D(a='foo')
>>>> d1.update(d2)
>>>> print d1['a']
foo # but 42 in PyPy
```

Answer (score 1):

Use hooky, http://hooky.readthedocs.com

Example for `hooky.List`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from hooky import List


class MyList(List):
    def _before_add(self, key, item):
        print('before add, key: {}, item: {}'.format(key, repr(item)))

    def _after_add(self, key, item):
        print(' after add, key: {}, item: {}'.format(key, repr(item)))

    def _before_del(self, key):
        print('before_del, key: ', key)

    def _after_del(self, key):
        print(' after_del, key: ', key)


l = MyList(['a', 'b'])

l.append(1)

l.extend(['f', 'g', 2])

l.pop()

l[2:3] = ['c', 'd', 'e']

print(l)

l.clear()

print(l)
```

print out:

```
before add, key: 0, item: 'a'
 after add, key: 0, item: 'a'
before add, key: 1, item: 'b'
 after add, key: 1, item: 'b'
before add, key: 2, item: 1
 after add, key: 2, item: 1
before add, key: 3, item: 'f'
 after add, key: 3, item: 'f'
before add, key: 4, item: 'g'
 after add, key: 4, item: 'g'
before add, key: 5, item: 2
 after add, key: 5, item: 2
before_del, key:  -1
 after_del, key:  -1
before_del, key:  2
 after_del, key:  2
before add, key: 2, item: 'c'
 after add, key: 2, item: 'c'
before add, key: 3, item: 'd'
 after add, key: 3, item: 'd'
before add, key: 4, item: 'e'
 after add, key: 4, item: 'e'
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
before_del, key:  -1
 after_del, key:  -1
before_del, key:  -1
 after_del, key:  -1
before_del, key:  -1
 after_del, key:  -1
before_del, key:  -1
 after_del, key:  -1
before_del, key:  -1
 after_del, key:  -1
before_del, key:  -1
 after_del, key:  -1
before_del, key:  -1
 after_del, key:  -1
[]
```